# Using volatile for a shared variable between WinAPI threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

The C++ compiler does not know anything about threads, the C++ compiler sees a "thread" simply as a function.

Now say I have two threads/functions, and I have one global variable.

If I am accessing the global variable in these two threads/functions, the C++ compiler could optimize the variable access code in these two threads and copy the global variable into a register and start manipulating the register and not the memory location. Now since each thread have a unique set of registers, if these two threads are running simultaneously, then they will not be accessing the global variable in memory, but rather each thread is manipulating its own register!

So if I make the global variable `volatile`, then this will tell the C++ compiler not to optimize the access code for the variable, and always access the memory location directly.

Is this correct?

Comment: *Is this correct?* No it is not: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The referred document says that the volatile object access is not optimized away, but using a cast and using (a) a non-volatile reference or (b) a (dereferenced) pointer of type "pointer to non-volatile" results in UB. Hey, don't blame the compiler for modification you did.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. No. Maybe.

In modern, standard, cross platform c++ `volatile` is neither *necessary* nor *sufficient* to achieve what you are doing. Just because you tell the compiler not to optimize out the read you do not tell the cpu/memory that the read/write shouldn't be re-ordered. And the standard also says that reading from somewhere whilst you may also be writing to it is *undefined behavoir*. You may get away with it on x86/x64 due to their unreasonably strong memory models but you shouldn't take the risk. `volatile` is for drivers and os's to talk to hardware.

You should use the modern way of doing this which is using a
`std::atomic<...>`. You can safetly read and write simultaneously to a `std::atomic` and reads/writes will not be optimized away*. Its simply the right choice.

However... if you are writing exclusively for Windows and using a flavor of Visual Studio then that compiler gives additional guarantees when using `volatile` that will work in your case with the right compiler options. VS increases the strength of the guarantee for `volatile` to similar to what C# & Java uses volatile for. It means in your case it will work. On the latest version of VS you can control this behavoir through [/volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204392.aspx) compiler option. HOWEVER, I do not recommend doing this unless its necessary. Use the standard std::atomic's unless you dont have a choice.

Note that C++/Java and VS's extension for volatile is actually weaker than using `std::atomic`. `std::atomic`'s guarantee *sequential consistancy* which neither Java nor C# do which means [Dekkers algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Dekker%27s_algorithm) can be used with std::atomic.

*`std::atomic`'s actually can be optimised out but only if you couldn't possibly notice under the as-if rule. This is another reason they're better than `volatile` which break optimizations as it simply MUST be done even if unnecessary as its impossible for the compiler to reason about.

Comment: What if I am not using VC++ and I am not using C++11, this means `std::atomic` does not exists. So how should I share a variable between two WinAPI threads in this case?

Comment: @paul It depends on what you are using

Comment: @paul: [Interlocked Variable Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122.aspx) will be worth a read.

Comment: @paul: depending on the nature of the variable, you could use the Interlocked API, or you could wrap the variable access using a critical section, mutex, SRW lock or other suitable [inter-thread synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681924.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: do you happen to know whether it is guaranteed that claiming a critical section (for example) creates a memory barrier?  The API documentation doesn't mention it that I could find.