# Can't exit loops dynamically while using keyboard hook

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, keyboard-hook

I'm having some issues about exiting "while" loops while using keyboard hook. Here is my code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT key = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN && nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {

    }

    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        if (key->vkCode == VK_CAPITAL) {
            capslockState = GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001;
            myLoop(capslockState);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And here is my function:

```
int myLoop(int a) {
    while (a == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // do some stuff
        }
        if (a == 0) {
            break;
            return 0;
        } 
        else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried couple more ways to achieve my goal but I couldn't do it. My goal is: I want to open the program, doesn't matter if Caps Lock is on or off, if I hit Caps Lock, it'll start my loop and if I hit it again, it'll stop. I was, somehow, able to make it using lots of "while" loops and threads but it was using almost all my CPU power. How can I create a performance friendly, dynamic loop while using keyboard inputs?
  Thank you.

Comment: The `myLoop` function is broken -- it fails to return a value despite having non-void return type.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm trying to get Caps Lock's state. If it's changed then exit the loop and wait for another change. What should I use instead of int function?

Comment: `break;` followed by `return 0;` - the `return` statement will never be executed.

Comment: Also, you only run the loop if `a == 1` so testing for `a == 0` inside the loop is useless.

Comment: @SidS So, what should I do? I'm really confused :) How can I recreate that function? I want to keep the `for` loop but I have to check if the state is changed after every loop.

Comment: Also, if I use `while(1)` , it uses too much CPU power.I don't want to use that.

Comment: @noobiecoder Does the answer solve your issue? Feel free let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is: I want to open the program, doesn't matter if Caps Lock is
>   on or off, if I hit Caps Lock, it'll start my loop and if I hit it
>   again, it'll stop.

You can check the following code to see if it works.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)  // do not process message 
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode,
            wParam, lParam);

    if (wParam == VK_CAPITAL) {

        if(hThread == NULL)
            hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, myLoop, NULL, 0, NULL); 

        if (capslockState)
            capslockState = 0;
        else
            capslockState = 1;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

DWORD WINAPI myLoop(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while (1) {
        for (UINT16 i = 0; (i < n && capslockState == 1); i++) {
            // do some stuff
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I made main edits on your code:

1. To make main thread can response to messages and keep your for loop, you need create a new thread([CreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-threads)) for running your for loop.
2. Since you "doesn't matter if Caps Lock is on or off" so no need check if the capslock is [on or off state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate).
3. To check the which key is hit use [wParam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984(v=vs.85).aspx) to compare with [virtual-key code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx).
4. Problems have pointed by others.

More reference "[Using Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-hooks)"

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your answer. I wasn't able to start the program when I copied your code to my source. Also, I didn't want to use `while(1)`. But then, I implemented couple lines of your code to my source and happy ending :) But still, I'm wondering, that created thread `hThread` is gonna live forever? Or it will be terminated at some point? Like, if I hit Caps Lock, it'll create a thread and then if I hit it again, that thread will be terminated. Do I have to add "terminate thread" code?

Comment: @noobiecoder I use `while(1)` since you said: "I want to keep the for loop". Yes, you can terminate the thread. **Note: TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases.** Refer to ["TerminateThread"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread#remarks) more detailed information.

Comment: @noobiecoder Also **note** the sample code in my answer is just a simple sample to show how to complete you function and I don't care more detailed implementation like thread safe that using glable varible like `capslockState`. Refe to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935745/using-volatile-for-a-shared-variable-between-winapi-threads) more information.